# SDL2 png image won't load

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have tried many (more than 10) SDL2 example files for C & C++ that load images and any that attempt to load png fails.

The C code below is about as simple and well commented as I can find and it has the same problem.

***The code works fine with bmp images*** but will not work for a ***png file***. (I am compiling from a win7 batch file using minGW.

This line causes the error when using .png but works for bmp... 
*SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("smile.bmp");*

Full code listing

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
    #include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

    int main(int argc, char* args[])
    {
      // attempt to initialize graphics and timer system
      if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
      {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        getchar(); // show error message, hit any key to quit
        return 1;  // return error value
      }

// load support for the JPG and PNG image formats
int flags=IMG_INIT_JPG|IMG_INIT_PNG;
int initted=IMG_Init(flags);
if((initted&flags) != flags) {
    printf("IMG_Init: Failed to init required jpg and png support!\n");
    printf("IMG_Init: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    // handle error
}

      SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 image library test",
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                         400, 400, 0);
      if (!win)
      {
        printf("error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        getchar(); // show error message, hit any key to quit
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1; // return error value
      }

      // print video card drivers
      SDL_RendererInfo info;
        int cnt, iDrivers;
        iDrivers = SDL_GetNumRenderDrivers();
        while ( cnt < iDrivers )
        {
          if ( SDL_GetRenderDriverInfo(cnt,&info) == 0 )
          {
            printf("%s\n",info.name);
          }
          cnt++;
        }  


      // create a renderer, which sets up the graphics hardware
      Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG;
      SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, render_flags);
      if (!rend)
      {
        printf("error creating renderer: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        getchar(); // show error message, hit any key to quit
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1; // return error value
      }

      // load the image into ram memory using SDL_image library function
      SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("smile.png");
      if (!surface)
      {
        printf("error creating surface: %s \n", SDL_GetError());
        getchar(); // show error message, hit any key to quit
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1; // return error value
      }

      // load the image data into the graphics hardware's memory
      SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, surface);
      SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
      if (!tex)
      {
        printf("error creating texture: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        getchar(); // show error message, hit any key to quit
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
      }

      SDL_RenderClear(rend);       // clear the window

      SDL_RenderCopy(rend, tex, NULL, NULL); // draw the image to the window
      SDL_RenderPresent(rend);

      SDL_Delay(10000);           // pause 10 seconds before quitting

      SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);    // clean up resources before exiting
      SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
      SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
      SDL_Quit();
      return 0;                   // return success value
    }
```

### UPDATE

[SOLVED] With the help of many contributors below, I was able to eventually feel confident the program was correct and I had some type of installation problem. After a good nights sleep I downloaded and reloaded ***mingw, SDL2_image, and zlib***, making sure I used 64bit versions. ***I am happy to report the problem has gone away.***

To assist anyone in the future, the initialization code

```
int flags=IMG_INIT_JPG|IMG_INIT_PNG;
int initted=IMG_Init(flags);
```

recommended by *"Roger Rapid & Keltar"* is not absolutely necessary (SDL2 can figure this out dynamical) but having it is highly recommended because it helps trap errors, which was useful in this case. For that reason I have left it in this code listing.

I am not quick to use forums but after 4 days I just didn't have a clue what could be causing the problem.

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Have you tried `printf("IMG_Load: %s\n", IMG_GetError());` to find out what the actual error is?

Comment: Was your SDL library compiled with PNG support?

Comment: When I place your code into an empty SDL2 project, the code compiles and runs for me, even with a PNG. I'm currently on a Mac, not sure if that makes a difference. Have you tried initialising SDL Image? `int flags = IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG;
int initted = IMG_Init( flags );`

Comment: @Weather Vane - the win cmd window opens and closes too fast for me to read it. Is there some way to keep it open after the error?

Comment: Put an input prompt after the error message?

Comment: got this message "error creating renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver"

Comment: So now search for "Couldn't find matching render driver" there are quite a lot of hits including previous SO questions.

Comment: I updated my video card driver to the latest (nVideo) and found a SDL program to report the drivers; I have: [direct3d - opengl - opengles2 - software] Should it say something like "SDL2"?

Comment: @jwzumwalt you haven't initialised SDL_image with required image formats (see Roger Rapid's comment). Also SDL_image never sets said error message, where exactly did you put this `printf`?

Comment: Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG; I have updated the program listing above.

Comment: @jwzumwalt not that, `SDL_Init` and `IMG_Init` are different functions. You'll also need `libpng` and `zlib` dynamic libraries for PNG loader to function.

Comment: @keltar - did it and updated the code above. I hope it is the right code and at the right place. New error messages: < IMG_Init: Failed to init required jpg and png...IMG_Init: Failed loading libpng16-16.dll > Thx I think this is progress. I put libpng16-16.dll every directory including win system32 - but still get the error.

Comment: It depends on `zlib1.dll`, have to have the same architecture as your `exe`, and if your system is 64bit, only 64bit libraries reside in `system32` while 32bit are in `syswow64` (sarcasm mode: because of course they are, who would have thought otherwise).

Comment: Thx, that seems too be correct. I have been at this for three days and I need a break. I'll get back at it after a little sleep - thx again for the help.but its all there